# How can I quickly set a field of all instances of a Django model at once?

Tags: python, django, performance, django-queryset

To clarify, I've got several thousands of Property items, each with a 'present' field (among others). To reset the system for use again, I need to set every item's 'property' field to false. Now, of course there's the easy way to do it, which is just:

```
for obj in Property.objects.all():
    obj.present = False
    obj.save()
```

But this takes nearly 30 seconds on my development server. I feel there must be a better way, so I tried limiting the loaded fields using Django's `only` queryset:

```
for obj in Property.objects.only('present'):
    obj.present = False
    obj.save()
```

For whatever reason, this actually takes **longer** than just getting the entire object.

Because I need to indiscriminately set all of these values to False, is there a faster way? This function takes no user input other than the 'go do it' command, so I feel a native SQL command would be a safe option, but I don't know SQL enough to draft such a command.

Thanks everyone.

Comment: How about update ? `Property.objects.all().update(present=False)`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the [`update`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.update) query:

```
Property.objects.all().update(present=False)
```

Note that `update()` query runs at SQL level, so if your model has a custom `save()` method then it is not going to be called here. In that case, the normal for-loop version that you're using is the way to go.

Comment: 8 Seconds. That's pretty awesome. Thank you very much! EDIT: To springboard off of this, changing it to Property.objects.filter(present=True).update(present=False) brought it down to 6.5-7 seconds. Great stuff!